# Psychopy: delayed picture display in an EEG experiment

Tags: triggers, delay, timing, psychopy

I'm running an EEG experiment with pictures and I send trigger over the parallel port. I added triggers to my code via Psychopy builder and synchronized it to screen refresh. I used a photo diode to test if pictures are displayed at exactly same time as the trigger is sent and I find irregular delays: a triggers is sent between 5ms and 26ms earlier than an image is actually displayed.

I don't think that an image size is an issue as I observed the delays even when I replaced pictures with a small-size white image. Moreover, there is an ISI period of half a second before a picture display which should help. I was told by the technicians that the graphic card or a cable should not be an issue.  Does anyone have an idea why I get these delays and how it could be solved?

Due to the comments, I'm adding a piece of code that sends a trigger:

```
# *image_training_port* updates
    if t >= 4.0 and image_training_port.status == NOT_STARTED:
        # keep track of start time/frame for later
        image_training_port.tStart = t  # underestimates by a little under one frame
        image_training_port.frameNStart = frameN  # exact frame index
        image_training_port.status = STARTED
        win.callOnFlip(image_training_port.setData, int(triggers_image_training))
    if image_training_port.status == STARTED and t >= (4.0 + (0.5-win.monitorFramePeriod*0.75)): #most of one frame period left
        image_training_port.status = STOPPED
        win.callOnFlip(image_training_port.setData, int(0))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be very good if you could include some code in your question that shows what you have tried so far and what your issue is.

Comment: Usually, questions about PsychoPy Builder are better asked at the PsychoPy forum, since it is not about coding. Go to http://discourse.psychopy.org. Wherever you ask, please include a screenshot of the relevant routine, settings, and any code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is most likely due to the monitor itself. Try swapping in a different monitor.

Explanation: Flat panel displays often do some "post-processing" on the frame pixels to make them look prettier (for flat panel TVs almost all of them do this). The post-processing is not only unwanted for the fact that it alters your carefully calibrated stimulus, but also because it can introduce delays if it takes longer than a few ms to perform. PsychoPy (or any software) can't detect this - it can only know about the time the frame was flipped at the level of the graphics card, not what happens after this.

Comment: Dear Jon, thank you for the response. Shouldn't the delays be constant then? And are you saying there is nothing I could do to improve the code to avoid at least some of these delays?

Comment: No, if the problem is the monitor doing post-processing on the frame image then it will not be constant and no there is nothing that better code will do to fix it (in any software package)